# Ruby On Rails log file name and line number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, log4r

Right now, I use log4r for logger in Rails to print file name and line number:

```
======== config/log4r.yml ========

log4r_config:
  # define all loggers:
  loggers:
    - name          : rails
      level         : DEBUG
      trace         : 'true'
      outputters    : 
      - console

  # define all outputters (incl. formatters)
  outputters:
  - type: StdoutOutputter
    name: console
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
      pattern     : '%d %l %t : %m'
      type        : PatternFormatter
```

However it prints file path instead of filename, and it's too long:

```
2015-12-23 18:05:37 INFO /Users/fudy/Workspace/RubyWorkspace/HelloWorld/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:3: in `index' : hello
```

But I want this format:

```
2015-12-23 18:05:37 INFO welcome_controller.rb:3: hello
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you sure this is the pattern you use? It looks more like '%d %p %t : %m' am I right?

Comment: Checked, it's the pattern I use

Comment: Sorry, thought you're using log4j and not log4r. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't show in the [documentation](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/Log4r/rdoc/patternformatter.html) but from looking at the [code](https://github.com/colbygk/log4r/blob/master/lib/log4r/formatter/patternformatter.rb) you can see that you should replace "t" with "T" to get only the file name.

The other option is to implement custom formatting like explained [here](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/Log4r/rdoc/formatter.html)